# Use hash or case-statement [Ruby]

Tags: ruby, hash, case

Generally which is better to use?:

```
case n
when 'foo'
 result = 'bar'
when 'peanut butter'
 result = 'jelly'
when 'stack'
 result = 'overflow'
return result
```

or

```
map = {'foo' => 'bar', 'peanut butter' => 'jelly', 'stack' => 'overflow'}
return map[n]
```

More specifically, when should I use case-statements and when should I simply use a hash?

Comment: These seem like odd things to compare. The case is logic and the hash is a data structure. Do you have a specific example where you are trying to decide which to use? The context will help people to provide a useful answer.

Comment: As a general note, the return statement can be (and often is) omitted in ruby methods.  In the case of your first example, you could actually remove both the return statements and the assignment to the `result` variable, assuming you're not doing anything with `result` other than returning it.

Comment: I've sometimes used user94154's approach, even though it's felt a little weird. I don't think it's a stupid question.

Comment: Just because it can be doesn't mean it shouldn't. Explicitly stating it makes the code easier for me to read. Also it makes it easier for any non-Rubyists to read. And I don't think it's not "the Ruby way" the way using a for loop instead of the each method might be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A hash is a data structure, and a case statement is a control structure.

You should use a hash when you are just retrieving some data (like in the example you provided).  If there is additional logic that needs to be performed, you should write a case statement.

Also, if you need to perform some pattern matching, it makes sense to use a case statement:

```
#pattern matching using ranges
letterGrade = case score
   when 0..64 then "F"
   when 65..69 then "D"
   when 70..79 then "C"
   when 80..89 then "B"
   when 90..100 then "A"
   else "Invalid Score"
end

#pattern matching using regular expressions
case songData
  when /title=(.*)/
    puts "Song title: #$1"
  when /track=(.*)/
    puts "Track number: #$1"
  when /artist=(.*)/
    puts "Artist name: #$1"
end
```

Answer (score 8):

In general, "better" in programming means different things. For example, better program

1. is easier to understand, i.e.
   expresses the intent better
2. is easier to maintain. For example,
   less lines of code, less
   error-prone, etc.
3. has better performance, in terms of
   execution time
4. has better performance, in terms of
   memory usage

etc.

Since we are talking about Ruby, the performance is typically of a lesser concern. If you really need performance, you might consider another programming language. So, I would look at criteria (1) and (2) first. The better looking Ruby code usually represents a "better" program. Which code looks better? Which expresses the intent better? Which would be easier to modify if you add/remove logic? It depends on your problem, and it's a matter of taste, to certain degree.

To me, in your short example, the hash solution is better. The case solution provides more flexibility, which you don't need in this case (but might need in other cases).

Answer (score 3):

There are two main differences between hash tables and case statements.

1. A hash table can be stored, modified, and reused within the lexical environment, whereas a case statement cannot. It produces a result and then disappears. Note however that if the case statement is within a block/method, it can of course be used multiple times by calling the block/method multiple times (but not easily modified).
2. A hash table literal expression always evaluates all of its keys and values, whereas a case statement only evaluates the "keys" it needs to and the "value" that it's going to return. This is often the more crucial difference, since the values could, as Derek B. points out, involve additional logic, which could be very costly to perform unnecessarily if only one of the values is needed.

.

```
case n
when 'foo'
 'bar'
when 'peanut butter'
 'jelly'
when 'stack'
 'overflow'
end
```

That's equivalent to your code, and after using Ruby or functional programming languages for a while, it will appear much more natural to you. It's also way shorter.